# Trying to replace part of array to another array, get error ValueError: assignment destination is read-only

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays with pixels, I need to replace the first part of array 'pixels_new', to array 'pixels_old'

```
pixels_old = numpy.asarray(im) #picture 100X100
pixels_new = numpy.asarray(img) #picture 100X200

for k in range(0,101):
   for i in range(len(pixels_old[k])):
       print(pixels_new[i])
       print(pixels_old[i])
       pixels_new[i] = pixels_old[i]
```

It gives me an error:

```
File "/Users/apple/Desktop/projects/BariySatarov/exercise22.py", line 48, in make_new_im
pixels_new[i] = pixels_old[i]
ValueError: assignment destination is read-only
```

Please help me with it

Comment: `asarray` doesn't make a copy if the source is already an array,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a simple test as below.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.asarray([1, 2, 3])
data[0] = 2
data
>>> array([2, 2, 3])
```

This shows `np.asarray` does not return the immutable variable, which is read-only. The error is `ValueError: assignment destination is read-only`. So, I think your `im` and `img` variables are immutable. You haven't included the source code for your `im` and `img`, so I couldn't tell much about this. However, I have one suggestion is that you should clone or convert your `im` and `img` into nd.array before proccessing.

Answer (score 0):

When we see this message :‍‍‍`ValueError: assignment destination is read-only`

We need to take two steps to solve it:

First:

```
print(pixels_new.flags)
```

output:

```
C_CONTIGUOUS : True
F_CONTIGUOUS : False
OWNDATA : False
WRITEABLE : False. ------> # this option must be True
ALIGNED : True
WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

then:

```
pixels_new.flags.writeable = True
```

The problem will be solved, but if the following message is given, do the following:

`ValueError: cannot set WRITEABLE flag to True of this array`

Make a copy of it so you can apply the changes to it:

```
pixel_n = pixels_new.copy()
pixels_n[i] = pixels_old[i]
```